# Detect tizen web app going to background?

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app

I need detect when my app moved to background by home pressed.

I try the next code:

```
document.addEventListener("pause", function(){
    console.log("pause");
}, false);

$("#main-page").focusout(function (){
    console.log("received focus Out Event") ;
});

$("#main-page").on("pagehide", function() {
    console.log("main-pagehide");
});

$("#main-page").on("pageremove", function() {
    console.log("main-pageremove");
});

$("#main-page").on("pagebeforehide", function() {
    console.log("main-pagebeforehide");
});
```

but when I pressed home nothing happens.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use the [`visibilitychange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/User_experience/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API) event, because this is the one which should be triggered in the scenario that you described (home button pressed).

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
    console.log("visibilitychange");
    if (document.hidden) {
        console.log('document hidden');
    } else  {
        console.log('document visible');
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. The anonymous function doesn't seem to get called at all. 
Are there any other possible solutions?

Comment: The above should be supported, but if it's not, you might try with `webkitvisibilitychange` instead of `visibilitychange` and `document.webkitHidden` instead of `document.hidden`

Comment: Thanks, we tried again, there was just a problem with the logger, which gave me the impression, it wasn't supported.